# How to query ifc files?

Tags: ifc, bim

I'm working on a project with BIM for my education and I want to extract data from ifc files.

The idea is to find information like finding floors with a specific height, shape and structure, then I would like to run pathfinding algorithms.

I can't find any document describing and comparing all possibilities...

I found some ways to query but most of them seems abandoned and others have drawbacks, here is what I have:

- BIMQL : no activity since 2017
- QL4BIM : no activity
- SPARQL : no comparison operators
- BIMServer query language : requires to run a server
- IFC++ : lack of documentation

I don't mind if the query language structure ( even if json would be awesome ).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about pathfinding, but did you look at [xBIM](https://github.com/xBimTeam)? 
It has documentation, examples and a [viewer](http://docs.xbim.net/downloads/xbimxplorer.html), so you can explore objects/hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the above [BIM_POC](https://github.com/shubhambansal500/bim_site_manager) , this should help you.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have some programming knowledge/experience, I suggest IfcOpenShell for all sorts of query and data extraction from ifc file.